# A suggestion as to set xy-pic as GUI into WinEdt

Tags: installing, xy-pic, winedt

With this question I don't know the procedure how to install into [WinEdt](http://www.winedt.org/) editor the GUI interface for the `Xy-Pic diagrams`.

Thanks to everyone for a help.

I have read the instructions here http://www.winedt.org/old/Config/GUI/Xy-pic.php, but have not been able to activate the window to activate `Xy-Pic` GUI into Winedt.

Comment: Hi Sebastiano I had hoped others could have given their customisation to you by now, my understanding is the system changed a lot so the installer cannot be easily changed to work as given it requires specially new modified approach. Its not a new gui but just one extra customised menu Diagrams section after AMS NOT =<>  in winedit gui  It involves a fair bit of repetitive editing and I only changed a few entries as proof of concept, I would need to tidy what I tested if you know you will be using them to ensure my time is not wasted

Comment: @KJO Dear KJO. In the meantime, I thank you for your comment and for your clarifications on this matter. After a few days I edited my question to make it a little clearer with the hope that someone had answered me. Unfortunately for various reasons I am not going through a good time. And then with English I am denied :-). Very often I have to technically understand the suggestions and indications. (+1)

Comment: Sebastiano your enthusiasm is noted. My grasp of other languages is much worse than your command of English.

Comment: @KJO :-) Thank you so much for your previous comment. Your English language is better than mine. It is surely.

Comment: I cannot understand the language of my birth, but living in England I should understand English well :-)

Comment: @KJO Again against me another serial downvote.

Comment: I see no reason for down votes your question whilst editor specific is potentionally side-topic but as it is how to inject tex macros into a tex file I feel it is on topic one of the reasons I investigated a solution hence my +1 for the question

Comment: @KJO Thank you, but as you well know, I'm not seeking votes. I'm worried about my situation which I'm always under attack. My most sincere greetings.

Comment: We all get random -1 I try not to worry over it there are more random +'s sometimes it seems unjust and I may have given the opposite value when the page shifted or my understanding of question/answer was wrong but the system often will not allow me to reverse a wrong decision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu system of WinEdt has changed a lot since that package was crafted, so whilst the installer places the macros and images in reasonable locations, it cannot integrate itself to the menu as it once did.

It requires a specially modified approach, where we add one extra customised `Diagrams` menu section after `AMS NOT =<>` in WinEdt gui.ini based in principle on the old xy.gui

There are some unfinished issues to address, see how the older large icons do not look right using the old icon values, so there are some unresolved issues to be investigated, OR make extra icons to suite NOTE the old icons are in one folder, newer icons are in 3 sizes ?

[image]

It involves a fair bit of repetitive editing, and I used find/replace so will just simply provide the modified section for you to test.

```
PAGE="Diagrams"
  CAPTION="Diagrams"
  CONFIG_FILTER=""
  MODE_FILTER=""
  GROUP="%B\Bitmaps\GUI\Xy-pic\pushback.bmp"
    TOP=0
    SPACE=0
    ROWS=1
    COLUMNS=2
    WIDTH=55
    HEIGHT=40
    ITEM="Pushout, Xy-pic"
      MACRO="Exe('%B\Macros\Xy-pic\pushout.edt');"
    ITEM="Pullback, Xy-pic"
      MACRO="Exe('%B\Macros\Xy-pic\pullback.edt');"
  GROUP="%B\Bitmaps\GUI\Xy-pic\rect.bmp"
    TOP=0
    SPACE=0
    ROWS=1
    COLUMNS=3
    WIDTH=49
    HEIGHT=40
    ITEM="Rectangular (n x m), Xy-pic"
      MACRO="Exe('%B\Macros\Xy-pic\rectang.edt');"
    ITEM="Cubic, Xy-pic"
      MACRO="Exe('%B\Macros\Xy-pic\cubic.edt');"
    ITEM="Lift Square, Xy-pic"
      MACRO="Exe('%B\Macros\Xy-pic\lift.edt');"
  GROUP="%B\Bitmaps\GUI\Xy-pic\triag1.bmp"
    TOP=0
    SPACE=0
    ROWS=1
    COLUMNS=4
    WIDTH=50
    HEIGHT=40
    ITEM="Bottom Triangle"
      MACRO="Exe('%B\Macros\Xy-pic\b-triag.edt');"
    ITEM="Top Triangle, Xy-pic"
      MACRO="Exe('%B\Macros\Xy-pic\t-triag.edt');"
    ITEM="Left Triangle, Xy-pic"
      MACRO="Exe('%B\Macros\Xy-pic\l-triag.edt');"
    ITEM="Right Triangle, Xy-pic"
      MACRO="Exe('%B\Macros\Xy-pic\r-triag.edt');"
  GROUP="%B\Bitmaps\GUI\Xy-pic\triag2.bmp"
    TOP=0
    SPACE=0
    ROWS=1
    COLUMNS=4
    WIDTH=45
    HEIGHT=40
    ITEM="Top-Right Triangle, Xy-pic"
      MACRO="Exe('%B\Macros\Xy-pic\tr-triag.edt');"
    ITEM="Lower-Right Triangle, Xy-pic"
      MACRO="Exe('%B\Macros\Xy-pic\lr-triag.edt');"
    ITEM="Lower-Left Triangle, Xy-pic"
      MACRO="Exe('%B\Macros\Xy-pic\ll-triag.edt');"
    ITEM="Top-Left Triangle, Xy-pic"
      MACRO="Exe('%B\Macros\Xy-pic\tl-triag.edt');"
  GROUP="%B\Bitmaps\GUI\Xy-pic\exact.bmp"
    TOP=0
    SPACE=0
    ROWS=1
    COLUMNS=1
    WIDTH=90
    HEIGHT=40
    ITEM="Exact Sequence (n), Xy-pic"
      MACRO="Exe('%B\Macros\Xy-pic\exact.edt');"
  GROUP="%B\Bitmaps\GUI\Xy-pic\cd.bmp"
    TOP=0
    SPACE=0
    ROWS=1
    COLUMNS=1
    WIDTH=49
    HEIGHT=40
    ITEM="Commutative Diagram (n x m), AmSTeX"
      MACRO="Exe('%B\Macros\Xy-pic\cd.edt');"
```

**Where to add the new menu** (Infographic with instruction below)

[image]

1) Open Option Interface and Locate tex symbols section in your gui.ini (it is highlighted in my picture on left)
2) Right Click <kbd>Open</kbd>

3) **Recommended** File Save **Copy** as **gui.ini-backup** (anything that you will remember later)

4) Go to the end (around Line 1680 in my version)
5) Just **before** the end line // ============ paste the extra code above with a blank line above and below , so the // ============ line moves down to about 1757 in my case.
6) File Save, I suggest exit WinEdt so it is forced to start afresh

7) When you re-enter WinEdt if you don't see the <kbd>diagrams</kbd> tab it is using the system menu   instead of your personal copy, then you need to over write the master copy in WinEdt folders (back-up)
8) If you need to force a gui icon rebuild right click the tex symbols entry and press F9
9) **If you don't see the icons** then they were not installed in the correct %B master location so follow the old installation instructions (ignoring any old comment about gui edits)

Comment: I understood it a little, but if you also inserted additional screenshots and as detailed as possible for me it's better. I'm not technically prepared :-( with WinEdt. Anyway I gladly accept your answer and thank you.

Comment: I have added some walk through illustration of adding the NEW section above to the menu You may not see icons if the old installer did not work well. But you must follow the instructions in `readme.1st` if you have problems with that part let me know

Comment: You are, also, a great! Thnak you very much with a lot heart.